# Adding a security feature to the ssh login

Tags: linux, bash, security, ssh

I'm setting up a new server and want to make it more secure. I just want to have some advice whether what I have done below is fine or useless

Assuming there is only one unix user available, no password authentication is allowed (only private/public key authentication). But if the private key is stolen, then anyone can access the ssh. 
So what I have done is: edited the .bashrc to add a custom script so that I ask a "security question". If the answer is right, then you are logged in, if not an email is sent and you are logged out.

In .bashrc:

```bash
trap printout INT
nb=1
printout() {
        case $nb in
        1)
                printf "\nAlert - Trying to escape?"
                nb=$((nb + 1))
                ;;
        2)
                printf "\nError - Email has been sent and a police patrol is on their way to your home.\n"
                #mail command to send an email
                exit
                ;;
        esac
}

read -rp "What's my favorite game? " Game
if [ "$Game" != "Anything you want" ]; then
  printf "\nAccess denied. Email has been sent and a police patrol is on their way to your home.\n"
#mail command to send an email
  exit
fi
echo "OK."
```

Comment: Create your certificates with passphrases.  This way if someone steals the private key, they cannot use it anyway.  A bank I worked at would create the keys for you with passphrase.  You could not create your own.

Comment: This is a very bad idea, firstly it's easy to bypass, secondly as @Nick3500 correctly stated, encrypting your SSH key has the same desired effect and provides far better protection.

Answer (score 2):

There are better security implementations for the ssh service.

- Change the authentication method from password to certificate (ref https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-creating_ssh_ca_certificate_signing-keys);
- Implement port-knocking on the ssh service (ref https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-port-knocking-to-hide-your-ssh-daemon-from-attackers-on-ubuntu);
- And if isn't enough, implement Fail2Ban on the ssh service (ref https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04);